# Cocos2d v3 CCButton conflicting with UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: objective-c, button, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I've added a UIGestureRecognizer to a class which hinerits from NSObject, and I'm handling the gestures with the UIGestureRecognizers, but I need to add an upper layer and add some CCButton on it, so to conceptualize my hierarchy would be pretty much this:

```
- CCScene
-- CCNode added to the scene (with the gesture recognizers)
-- another CCNode added with a few CCButton
```

the UIGestureRecognizers are working well, but the CCButton is never called because the touch is handled by the gestures, if I remove the gestures, the CCButton is called

they are in conflict and I don't know why, I've read that the CCNodes touches are swallowed starting from the first (in term of hierarchy, where the first is the bigger z order I think) until the last, so since both my CCNode are added to the scene, and since the second ccnode (added with a bigger z order) is the first I think it should get the touch BEFORE the UIGestureRecognizer of the other ...

what I'm missing?

here's how I've added the gestures:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.myClassImplementation action:@selector(gesture:)];

[tapGesture setDelegate:self.myClassImplementation];

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:myGesture];
```

I tried to simply add the CCButton directly into the CCScene but isn't called, can someone explain to me why they are in conflict? so to find I way to make it works

Answer (score 0):

Gesturerecognizers get all the standard responder touch events. So you should handle it in gesturerecognizer's delegate method or in gesture action.

Here is how you can do it in delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: [touch locationInView:touch.view]];
    CCResponderManager *responder = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] responderManager];
    CCNode *node = [responder nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

    if([node isKindOfClass:[CCButton class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"button");
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not button");
        return YES;
    }
}
```